# Yelp Tableau Web Data Connector

Tags: api, tableau-api

i'm new to tableau web data connectors and programming but i'm attempting to create a yelp data connector.

- I tested the API using postman and it works fine.
- I copied the sample earth quake js code snippets that tableau github
  provided into my Yelp.js.
- The API also needs a private API key which i added into my Yelp.js
  file.

**When i press get data, the WDC Validation error pop up appears.**

Here are the error messages in the console:

**"Data type can't be blank"**

[image]

**This is the Yelp.js file that i have, not too sure what the error message is refering to?**

**Define the schema that the datasource will have** <-- Seems like this schema here is the issue? But it's not blank..

```
myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
    //Each item represents a column in tableau
    var cols = [{
        id: "term",
        alias: "search term",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
    }, {
        id: "location",
        alias: "location",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
    }, {
        id: "latitude",
        alias: "lat",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.decimal
    }, {
        id: "longitude",
        alias: "lon",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.decimal
    }, {
        id: "radius",
        alias: "radius",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.tnteger
    }, {
        id: "open_now",
        alias: "open now",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.boolean
    }, {
        id: "open_at",
        alias: "open at",
        dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.integer
    }];

    var tableInfo = {
        id: "yelpsearch",
        alias: "Yelp Business Search",
        columns: cols
    };
```

**The following code snippets is to download the data**

```
myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
    var term = "",
        location = "",
        latitude = 0,
        longitude = 0,
        radius = 0,
        open_now = true,
        open_at = 0;
```

**Copied from Postman**

```
  var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search",
        "method": "GET",
         "headers": {
           "Authorization": "Bearer API KEY HERE",
          "cache-control": "no-cache",
          "Postman-Token": "POSTMAN TOKEN HERE"
        }
      }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
```

**Iterate over the JSON object**

```
    $.getJSON("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", function(resp) {
            tableData = [];


        for (var i = 0, len = resp.length; i < len; i++) {
            tableData.push({
            "term" : resp[i].term,
            "location" : resp[i].location,
            "latitude" : resp[i].latitude,
            "longitude": resp[i].longitude,
            "radius" : resp[i].radius,
            "open_now" : resp[i].open_now,
            "open_at" : resp[i].open_at,


            });

        }

        table.appendRows(tableData);
        doneCallback();
    });
};
```

Would appreciate if anyone can shed some light into this. Thanks!

This is the API documentation for Yelp

https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search